# How do I inspect and activate other application’s menu?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, macos

Is it possible to inspect the main application menu of some already running application and execute commands from this menu? For example retrieve the whole main menu hierarchy of Safari and execute the File → New Tab command (by its name, not using the keyboard shortcut). I’m interested in an Objective-C solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way to do this is using the Cocoa [Accessibility API](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Accessibility/cocoaAXIntro/cocoaAXintro.html)

For example,

> NSAccessibilityPickAction Selects the
>   object, such as a menu item

Comment: To manipulate another application, you need the Carbon Accessibility API, not the Cocoa one. Both are available in 64-bit. http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Accessibility/Reference/AccessibilityCarbonRef/

Answer (score 2):

You could use [Applescript](http://developer.apple.com/AppleScript/) This is not exactly calling the menus but for a well written program provides the same functionality and using a defined and discoverable API.

To send the events see [Scripting Bridge](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ScriptingBridgeConcepts/Introduction/Introduction.html)